# How exactly is this new string variable created from this while loop algorithm in python?

Tags: python, random, while-loop, slice

guys. Thanks for taking the time to look through this. I've been having some trouble trying to figure out how exactly Python is creating this new string variable. The initial code is with a tuple full of random words. There is a random module that was imported and used the choice method to pull a random word out. Then, a while loop was created from that given variable that housed the random word that was just pulled. The objective was to completely randomize the lettering of the word. After words it prints the variable that holds the randomized indexed word. Here is the code I'm talking about

```
    import random

# create a sequence of words to choose from
WORDS = ("python", "jumble", "easy", "difficult", "answer", "xylophone")
# pick one word randomly from the sequence
word = random.choice(WORDS)
# create a variable to use later to see if the guess is correct
correct = word

# create a jumbled version of the word
jumble =""
while word:
    position = random.randrange(len(word))
    jumble += word[position]
    word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):]

print(jumble)
```

My question is, how exactly is python creating a brand new jumbled word? I understand the code and what is happening up until it reaches to this given part that has me confused on what's going on.

```
jumble += word[position]
word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):]
```

Comment: Do not know about the Python code, but split the problem: 1. pick a random word. 2. Shuffle the word itself, in mathematics that is called a permutation, you probably want a random permutation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During each iteration, you "move" one character from the original word to the jumbled one. This is actualy quite simple when you understand the syntax:

`jumble += word[position]` - Add to the jumbled word the character at the random position

`word = word[:position] + word[(position + 1):]` - Remove the character at position `position` from the original word `word`

If you add `print word, jumble` as the first line inside your while loop, you could see the words come to life :)

Comment: ahhhh I sort of get it. So in the case of this while loop... is it safe to say it's acting like a for loop in that the while loop condition specified is going through the entire length of the word variable itself?

Comment: @KennethStevenMcAuslandJr. you could say that. `for x in xrange(len(word)):` would have worked here as well

Comment: well thanks, Daniel! If you don't mind, could I pm you sometime later on this week for some upcoming while loop exercises I'm building for myself?

Comment: @KennethStevenMcAuslandJr. Sure, go ahead, I'll try to help point you in the right direction.